# How to display findAll from JSON with Ember-data, in View?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to display a list populated with data from a JSON file. I would use a modified Adapter. Here's [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/besign/P3eUP/) so far, including path to the test json file (since I'd hope to get some help without the use of FIXTURES)

I'm unsure on how to pushObject for results using Ember-Data. I know I'm probably still not getting some concepts for Ember-Data.

My question is: How do I get a list from the JSON file based on the following code.

**JavaScript**

```
    App = Em.Application.create();

    App.store = DS.Store.create({
      revision: 4,
      adapter: App.adapter
    });

    App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({

        findAll: function (store, type) {
            console.log('finding');
            var url = type.url;
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                store.loadMany(type, data);
            });

        }

    });

    App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
        fName: DS.attr('string'),
        surname: DS.attr('string'),
        url: 'test.json',
    });
    App.personController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [],
        init: function(){
            this._super();// create an instance of the person model
            this.set('person', App.store.findAll(App.Person));
        },
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{#each App.personController}}            
        <p>{{fName}} {{surname}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I´ve updated the code in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/besign/P3eUP/2/) on @pauldechov recommendations, still no luck.

Here's the content for test.json, so the whole app can be recreated:

```
   [{"name": "Bruce","surname": "Banner"}, 
   {"name": "Peter","surname": "Parker"},
   {"name": "Natasha","surname": "Romanoff"},
   {"name": "Steve","surname": "Rogers"},
   {"name": "Tony","surname": "Stark"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The url property should be defined as such:

  ```
  App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
      fName: DS.attr('string'),
      surname: DS.attr('string'),
  }).reopenClass({ url: 'test.json' });
  ```

  ...as an instance variable rather than as a class variable (see example: https://github.com/emberjs/data#find). The way you defined it (or if you use `.reopen({...})` instead of `.reopenClass({...})`, it would be accessible via (a specific) person.url rather than type.url.
- AFAIK you can't add a .json file to jsfiddle's resources; it won't be accessible. Querying the full url of test.json yielded a cross domain issue.
- You may need to place the model(s) above App.adapter, above App.store. Try this if it's still failing.
- Peripheral observation: "name" in test.json vs. "fName" in the code?

Comment: I tried your recommendations, but still can't fetch data. Could you try out the code? You're right about jsfiddle not allowing cross domain links, I was just trying to put the json data accesible for revision, but I've now updated the Question, so all the information is available. All help very much appreciated!

Comment: I originally didn't reply with a fiddle because it didn't occur to me at the time how to bypass the AJAX call (not allowed by your server actually). See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/P3eUP/4/. a) I see that `App.store` must be defined below `App.adapter` -- wasn't certain of that before. b) Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that `type` should be `person` inside of the adapter definition. c) There's no need to have an explicit loading `{{action}}`, so I updated your original fiddle. In fact, you could avoid overriding `init` and just have `content: App.store.findAll(App.Person)`.

Comment: Awesome! Interesting how in Ember it could seem that order doesn't affect outcome, when in fact (and logically) it does.
Thank you so much for taking the time and for all the great recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

```
App.personController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){
        this._super();// create an instance of the person model
        this.set('person', App.store.findAll(App.Person));
    },
});
```

Why set `person`? Should it not be set `content`?

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Comment: because `this.set('person')` seems not to be correct. `this.set('content')` should do it